# Does Kotlin have macros?

Tags: kotlin, macros

I have the following peace of code:

```kotlin
class JiraCredentials(applicationContext: Context)
{
    private val preferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
        "jira",
        ComponentActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
    )

    private val username_key = "username"
    var username: String
        get () = preferences.getString (username_key, "").toString()
        set (value) {
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString (username_key, value)
            editor.commit ()
        }

    private val password_key = "password"
    var password: String
        get () = preferences.getString (password_key, "").toString()
        set (value) {
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString (password_key, value)
            editor.commit ()
        }
}
```

As you can see the "username" part is almost the same as the "password" part. Other languages (Scheme, Rust) have ["hygienic macros"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro) to handle this. What is the idiomatic way to handle this in Kotlin?

Comment: Isn't it enough to use just a function and passing a key as a function parameter?

Comment: @okarakose Maybe if the argument is an enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case, you can use property delegates to reduce the duplication.

```
class PreferenceDelegate(
    val key: String,
    val preferences: SharedPreferences
) {
    operator fun getValue(self: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) =
        preferences.getString(key, "").toString()

    operator fun setValue(self: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        val editor = preferences.edit()
        editor.putString(key, value)
        editor.commit()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var username by PreferenceDelegate("username", preferences)
var password by PreferenceDelegate("password", preferences)
```

If the key is always the same as the property name, then you can remove the `key` parameter since the key can be retrieved from `property.name`.

If you are only using this in `JiraCredentials`, you can remove the `preferences` parameter, since you can get that from `self.preferences`.

Here is an example with both parameters removed:

```
// this can be put inside JiraCredentials so that you can access "preferences"
object PreferenceDelegate {
    operator fun getValue(self: JiraCredentials, property: KProperty<*>) =
        preferences.getString(property.name, "").toString()

    operator fun setValue(self: JiraCredentials, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        val editor = self.preferences.edit()
        editor.putString(property.name, value)
        editor.commit()
    }
}

// Usage:
var username by PreferenceDelegate
var password by PreferenceDelegate
```

Comment: This seems to require [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/).

Comment: @ceving If you find the reflection API takes too long to load, you can avoid loading the reflection API by making the `operator fun`s `inline`. (This only works if you keep the `key` parameter and don't access `property.name`)

Comment: @ceving I just realised, an inline function cannot access private properties like `preferences`, so you must keep the `preferences` parameter too. This is because rather than inlining to where the properties are declared (like how a macro would behave), `inline` in this case would inline the code to where you get/set `username` and `password`.

Comment: [`getValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/get-value.html) requires a [`KProperty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/) argument. So this code uses always reflection to inspect the property, although the properties in my example are pretty static.

Comment: @ceving Well, if it is inlined, and your code doesn't access the `KProperty`, then it won't load the reflection API, will it? Check by putting a breakpoint on `ClassLoader.loadClass` (if that's a thing on Android - my experience with Android is limited).

Comment: No I love reflection. My prefered language is Scheme. But Kotlin is a statically typed language. And the use of runtime types in a case, where the types are not dynamic, seems to be the wrong way for a statically typed language.

Comment: @ceving *You* can choose to not use runtime types - just don't access `property.name`. It's just that property delegates, by design, need to take a `KProperty<*>`. It is given to you, but you don't need to use it at all. You can even avoid the overhead of loading the reflection API by making it `inline`. And I agree that this is a crappy design, and the community is trying to move away from this. See these feature requests: [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17034) and [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16997/More-flexible-delegated-property-convention).

Answer (score -1):

I just found out that some poeple try to implement something for Kotlin, which has a similar functionality. The effort is called [KotlinPoet](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet).